# Android: ActivityCompat.requestPermissons() not showing dialog

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth

I'm asking permission BLUETOOTH_SCAN but user dialog does not appear on the screen.

Here is my (compressed version of) MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String TAG = "MyBT";
    private static final int BT_SCAN_REQ_CODE = 1234;
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission BLUETOOTH_SCAN granted");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission BLUETOOTH_SCAN denied");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, BT_SCAN_REQ_CODE);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() finished");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, 
            int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == BT_SCAN_REQ_CODE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult(): " + grantResults.length + " result(s)");
            for (int r = 0; r < grantResults.length; r++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "grantResult = " + grantResults[r]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    }
```

When running the program there is now pop-up dialog asking for the permission, and I get the following LOG-output:

```
Permission BLUETOOTH_SCAN denied  
onCreate() finished  
onRequestPermissionsResult(): 1 result(s)  
grantResult = -1
```

What is wrong with my program? I tried to follow all the recommendations given in the Android IDE documentation.

My gradle parameters are:

```
compileSdk 33
minSdk 26
targetSdk 33

sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```